# Elasticsearch: How the anomaly detection works (in detail)?

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I am studying elasticsearch and I was very curious about the x-pack and it open source release. Since I wanted to dive deeper into these topics, I was wondering where I can find a detailed explanation/documentation on the Machine Learning in elasticsearch and specifically in the anomaly detection algorithm.

I have found some books, but I couldn't find anything detailed related to the content. Maybe someone can help me, these are the books:

- [Machine Learning with the Elastic Stack](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/machine-learning-with/9781788477543/)
- [Advanced Elasticsearch 7.0](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/advanced-elasticsearch-70/9781789957754/)

Comment: I had the same question. The ES code is open sourced on github so you can read how x-pack works there. They (sometimes) keep doc files for developers inside folders that gives useful code description that might be helpful

Comment: I have found some, but not really what I asked. Could you link me yours?